# Swift: Variable values don't carry over to didSet

Tags: swift, didset

This is my first project in Swift so please bear with me.

punkteLimit should be initialized with value 30. The value of the variable as well as a label should be updated everytime a slider value is changed.

```
var punkteLimit: Int = 30

@IBAction func sliderPunktelimitChanged(_ value: Float) {
    punkteLimit = Int(value)
    labelPunktelimit.setText("Punkte-Limit: \(punkteLimit)")
}
```

This seems to work fine. The label updates correctly, i.e. when I change the slider to 28, it says "Punkte-Limit: 28". However, punkteLimit is stuck at the initial value of 30 in the following part (the same is true for considerPunktelimit but the solution should be identical). The haptic feedback will be triggered at gesamtPunkte == 30 regardless of the changes above.

I use a button that performs gesamtPunkte += 1 to adjust the value, if it matters.

```
var gesamtPunkte: Int = 0 {
    didSet {
        if gesamtPunkte == punkteLimit && considerPunktelimit == true {
            WKInterfaceDevice.current().play(WKHapticType.stop)
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

I'm not exactly sure where to go from here.

Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by moving the variable(s) in question outside of the InterfaceController class (making them global?). I have read mixed opinion about this approach, if anyone wants to comment on why it didn't work inside of the class and whether or not there are problems with making them global, feel free to.